# How to yield inside an external callback function in react redux saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, tus

I'm using the *tus* Protocol to upload files and this protocol has some callback functions.
What I'm trying to do is to *yield* an action and do something else, but I see that I can't use **yield** inside the callback.

Bellow is a piece of code from the saga function that contains the callback.

```
const upload = new tus.Upload(payload,
{
            endpoint: `${baseURL}files/`,
            chunkSize: fileChunkSize, 
            headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwtToken}`, 'SelectedDatabase': selectedDatabase }, 
            onSuccess: () => {                        
                console.log("Upload Finished");
                toast.done(toastId);
                toastSuccess(`File (${payload.name}) was successfully uploaded.`);
                //yield put(sendFilesSuccess()); TODO: how to call this?
            }
}); 

upload.start();
```

I read something related to channels, but I couldn't understand it very well, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this upload function is inside a react component?

Comment: @Roy.B The React Component dispatches an action and the saga is listening to that action

Comment: Channels is what I would use too. I'll help give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great use case for Channels because they make handling event callbacks as if it were just like handling Redux actions. To wait and read from a channel, it's as simple as doing a `take`.

```
function uploadChannelCreator(payload, /* ... */) {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
      const upload = new tus.Upload(payload,
      {
            endpoint: `${baseURL}files/`,
            chunkSize: fileChunkSize, 
            headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwtToken}`, 'SelectedDatabase': selectedDatabase }, 
            onSuccess: () => {
                emitter('SUCCESS');
            }
            // ... Emit other messages based on different events (i.e. onFailure)
      }); 

      upload.start();

      return () => {}
    }
  )
}

function* uploadSaga(payload, /* ... */) {
    const chan = yield call(uploadChannelCreator, payload, /* ... */); // 1. Call Channel
    const msg = yield take(chan); // 2. Wait for channel to emit a message

    // Rest of code... (Add error handling if necessary).
    console.log("Upload Finished");
    toast.done(toastId);
    toastSuccess(`File (${payload.name}) was successfully uploaded.`);
}
```

Comment: Awesome man, this is working and I could understand the approach. Thanks a lot.